# Is it possible to include php files using AJAX() ?? in JQM mobile form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a form page for a mobile website . In my desktop version I was including some php files that contains some extra form elements . It looked something like this .

```
<div id="DIVC3" class="divs_details">
    <?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/cat3.tpl.php")?>
</div>
<div id="DIVC4" class="divs_details">
    <?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/cat4.tpl.php")?>
</div>
<div id="DIVC5" class="divs_details">
    <?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/cat5.tpl.php")?>
</div>
<div id="DIVC6" class="divs_details">
    <?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/cat6.tpl.php")?>
</div>
<div id="DIVC8" class="divs_details">
    <?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/cat8.tpl.php")?>
</div>
<div id="DIVC9" class="divs_details">
    <?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/cat9.tpl.php")?>
</div>
<div id="DIVC10" class="divs_details">
    <?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/cat10.tpl.php")?>
</div>
<div id="DIVC11" class="divs_details">
    <?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/cat11.tpl.php")?>
</div>
<div id="DIVC12" class="divs_details">
    <?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/cat12.tpl.php")?>
</div>
<div id="DIVC13" class="divs_details">
    <?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/cat13.tpl.php")?>
</div>
<div id="DIVC15" class="divs_details">
    <?php include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/cat15.tpl.php")?>
</div>
<div id="DIVC16" class="divs_details">
    <?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/cat16.tpl.php")?>
</div>
<div id="DIVC17" class="divs_details">
    <?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/cat17.tpl.php")?>
</div>
<div id="err_desc" style="visibility:hidden; display:none;">
    <?php
    $long_desc=strlen($t_POST['im_desc']);
    if ($long_desc>0 && $long_desc<15) {
        ?>
        <span style="color:#FF0000;font-weight:bold; font-size:12px"> <?=$this->translate->translate('ERR_DESC','nucleo','Descripción deficiente');?></span>
        <?php 
    }
</div>
```

But If i do this in mobile website it takes too long for the page to be loaded. So what I am thinking is like loading each page only when needed according to `Onchange()` event using `Ajax()` is it possible to include this way ??

**Script**

```
function includeFile(categoria) {
        if( categoria == (3))
{
        //here I want to include the file using Ajax()
}

}
```

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to load php with ajax. You only have to send your variables with Post or GET

something like this with jquery ajax:

`$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "bla/cat15.tpl.php",
      data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
    })
    .done(function( data) {
       $('#DIVC15').html(data);
    });`